# Cordova build windows on Windows 10 and VisualStudio 2017

Tags: windows, cordova, msbuild

Trying to build the Cordova App on Windows 10 always fails with
`(node:31) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target.`
on Windows 10 Pro 1709 with VisualStudio 2017 Community Edition.

I exactly followed all instructions for Windows 10 in the [cordova docs for windows](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/win8/index.html)

I have installed VS with package `Mobile Development with Javascript` which includes the cordova tools. I also installed the additional [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/de/downloads/).
To create the test app, I used the commands from the docs:

```
cordova create test
cd test
cordova platform add windows
cordova build windows
```

After hours of research, I found out the issue could be an active WindowsPolicy `DisableRegistryTools`, but this is not causing the issue. Reinstalling VisualStudio does also not have any effect. The error message is always the same.

Edit:
I just checked `cordova requirements`, I did not know that command before. This is the output:

```
Requirements check results for windows:
Windows OS: installed Windows 10
MSBuild Tools: not installed
MSBuild tools v.12.0 not found. Please install Visual Studio 2013 Express  for Windows Update2 from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-    studio-vs
Visual Studio: not installed
Required version of Visual Studio not found. Please install Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Update2 from     https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs
Windows SDK: not installed
Windows SDK not found. Ensure that you have installed Windows 8.1 SDK along with Visual Studio or install Windows 8.1 SDK separately from     https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads
Windows Phone SDK: not installed
Windows Phone SDK not found. Ensure that you have installed Windows Phone 8.1 SDK along with Visual Studio or install Windows Phone 8.1 SDK separately from https://dev.windows.com/develop/download-phone-sdk
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

If it is possible, I would try the required older version of VisualStudio. But the download is not available anymore.

Comment: Have you installed MSBuild? It should be sitting in `C:\Program Files\MSBuild`.

Comment: The MSBuild path does exist in `Program Files (x86)` and  `Program Files`. It seems for me to be installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got `cordova build windows` and `cordova run windows` working by following this [recently posted guide on the cordova blog](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/02/27/cordova-windows-6.0.0.html).

- Install [VistualStudio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) or better

  - **With options**:

    - Universal Windows Platform development,
      +add optional: Windows 10 Mobile-Emulator (Fall Creators Update)
      +add optional: Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) für UWP: C#, VB, JS
      +add optional: Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586.0)
    - Mobile development with JavaScript
      +add optional: Windows 10 Mobile-Emulator (Fall Creators Update)
      +add optinoal: UWP-Tools for Cordova
- Install [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017), you will find them on the VS downloads page in **Other Tools and Frameworks** section

  - The options below might not all be necessary, but I installed them all to get it just running.
  - **With options**:

    - Visual C++ Buildtools
      +add optional: Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) für Desktop C++
      +add optional: Visual C++-Tools für CMake
    - Buildtools for web development
      +add optional: Development tools für .NET Framework 4–4.6
      +add optional: .NET Core 2.0-Development tools
      +add optional: NuGet-Ziele und Buildaufgaben
      +add optional: TypeScript 2.6 SDK
      +add optional: Extended ASP.NET-Features
    - .NET Core-Buildtools
    - Node.js Buildtools

---

- Make sure to use `cordova platform add windows@6.0.0`
  otherwise 5.0.0 will be added to your project, which is mostly incompatible to VisualStudio 2017.
- Make sure to set `MSBUILDDIR` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`
- Make sure to **NOT use bash on Windows**, otherwise Cordova will not recognize you are on a Windows operating system. So you have to use **CMD** or **Powershell**.
- I also added these preferences to the config.xml

  ```
  <platform name="windows">
      <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
      <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
      <preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx://" />
  </platform>
  ```

  ### - If you still run into errors, try opening the project in Visual Studio and build there.
- If you are using **Ionic 3**, you can use **bash** to run `npm install`, `ionic cordova platform add windows@6.0.0` and `ionic cordova build windows --prod` to compile and copy to platform/www. But building the *.appx* package must be done with **CMD** using `cordova build windows` or `cordova run windows`
- If the App style remains Android-like, add this config to `app.module.ts`

  ```
   imports: [
     IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
         mode: 'wp',
     })
   ],
  ```

Comment: Yay, it works! (Looks like after installing older components [TS 2.6 SDK, Win10 10.0.*.0 SDKs ])